# When elliptic curve over local field can be regarded as Tate curve?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I'm completely beginner of Tate curve, sorry to ask a basic question.
I don't see for what condition, elliptic curves can be regarded as Tate curve or not.

For example, let $E_p:y^2=x^3+17x$ be an elliptic curve over $\Bbb{Q}_p$, for $p=2,17,37$. Here $2,17$ is bad prime of $E$ and $37$ is good prime of $E$.

For which $p$, is $E_p$ a Tate curve ?

Comment: Tell us what reference you are reading on this topic. Look at the “Properties” section of the Tate curve Wikipedia page to see some necessary conditions, such as $|j(E)|_p > 1$.